# Scraping SVG Chart using Selenium - Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, svg

I am trying to scrape the SVG chart which contains the previous months prices of the house, from the following URL: https://www.zameen.com/Property/dha_defence_dha_defence_phase_2_1_kanal_neat_and_clean_upper_portion_for_rent-24195800-339-4.html

I am scraping the "Price Index" section, image attached: [image: Price Index Image]

The code snippet is below:

```
elements = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value="//*[local-name() = 'svg' and @class='ct-chart-line']//*[name() = 'g' and @class='ct-labels']//span[contains(@class,'ct-horizontal')]")

print("WebElements: ", len(elements))

actions = ActionChains(driver)

for el in elements:
    
    actions.move_to_element(el).perform()
    time.sleep(1)
    print(driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="div.chartist-tooltip").text)
    print(driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="div.ct-axis-tooltip-x").text)
```

Following is the output I have received:

```
WebElements:  7
32,388,054 ==> Jun 2021
33,828,816 ==> Aug 2021
36,064,647 ==> Oct 2021
38,336,196 ==> Dec 2021
39,535,707 ==> Feb 2022
40,257,851 ==> Apr 2022
40,733,506 ==> May 2022
```

I am using the X-Axis Labels of Months as my elements and moving the selenium on it and capturing the price for that month. Unfortunately, the label of the months is of every 2 months and I get a total of 7 months of data rather than 12 months.

**What could be a better solution so I can get complete 12-month prices?**

Comment: _better solution_: Use a provider which offers an api.

Answer (score 2):

```
import requests

cookies = {}
headers = {'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'}

params = {
    'property_id': '24195800',
    'purpose': '2',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.zameen.com/nfpage/async/property/get_property_search_index', params=params, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
```

will return all data for the graph in nested dict format:

```
response.text
'{"status":"success","search_index_data":{"section_data":{"heading_txt":" Islamabad DHA Defence Phase 2, 1 Kanal Plots Price Index","heading_month":"May 2022"},"index_data":{"class":"inc","current_year":"2022","last_value":"235.60","ratio":135.6,"ratio_percent":135.6,"range":"100.00 - 235.60","weeks_range":"187.33 - 235.60","this_year_range":"225.89 - 235.60","start_date":"Jan 2018","end_date":"May 2022","end_date_formatted":"May 2022"},"price_data_per_unit":{"class":"inc","current_year":"2022","last_value":"9,052","ratio":"5,210","ratio_percent":135.6,"range":"3,842 - 9,052","weeks_range":"7,197 - 9,052","this_year_range":"8,679 - 9,052","start_date":"Jan 2018","end_date":"May 2022","end_date_formatted":"May 2022"},"price_data":{"class":"inc","current_year":"2022","last_value":"40,734,000","ratio":"23,445,000","ratio_percent":135.6,"range":"17,289,000 - 40,734,000","weeks_range":"32,386,500 - 40,734,000","this_year_range":"39,055,500 - 40,734,000","start_date":"Jan 2018","end_date":"May 2022","end_date_formatted":"May 2022"},"chart_data":{"0":{"moving_avg":"100.0000","org_moving_avg":"1.000000","period_end_date":"2018-01-31","slope":"1.000000"},"1":{"moving_avg":"101.5000","org_moving_avg":"1.015000","period_end_date":"2018-02-28","slope":"0.970000"},"2":{"moving_avg":"101.6667","org_moving_avg":"1.016667","period_end_date":"2018-03-31","slope":"0.980000"},"3":{"moving_avg":"102.3333","org_moving_avg":"1.023333","period_end_date":"2018-04-30","slope":"0.980000"},"4":{"moving_avg":"103.0000","org_moving_avg":"1.030000","period_end_date":"2018-05-31","slope":"0.950000"},"5":{"moving_avg":"104.3333","org_moving_avg":"1.043333","period_end_date":"2018-06-30","slope":"0.940000"},"6":{"moving_avg":"105.6667","org_moving_avg":"1.056667","period_end_date":"2018-07-31","slope":"0.940000"},"7":{"moving_avg":"106.3333","org_moving_avg":"1.063333","period_end_date":"2018-08-31","slope":"0.940000"},"8":{"moving_avg":"107.6667","org_moving_avg":"1.076667","period_end_date":"2018-09-30","slope":"0.910000"},"9":{"moving_avg":"108.3333","org_moving_avg":"1.083333","period_end_date":"2018-10-31","slope":"0.930000"},"10":{"moving_avg":"109.0000","org_moving_avg":"1.090000","period_end_date":"2018-11-30","slope":"0.920000"},"11":{"moving_avg":"108.3333","org_moving_avg":"1.083333","period_end_date":"2018-12-31","slope":"0.930000"},"12":{"moving_avg":"108.0000","org_moving_avg":"1.080000","period_end_date":"2019-01-31","slope":"0.930000"},"13":{"moving_avg":"107.6667","org_moving_avg":"1.076667","period_end_date":"2019-02-28","slope":"0.930000"},"14":{"moving_avg":"107.6667","org_moving_avg":"1.076667","period_end_date":"2019-03-31","slope":"0.930000"},"15":{"moving_avg":"108.6667","org_moving_avg":"1.086667","period_end_date":"2019-04-30","slope":"0.910000"},"16":{"moving_avg":"110.0000","org_moving_avg":"1.100000","period_end_date":"2019-05-31","slope":"0.890000"},"17":{"moving_avg":"112.3333","org_moving_avg":"1.123333","period_end_date":"2019-06-30","slope":"0.870000"},"18":{"moving_avg":"113.3333","org_moving_avg":"1.133333","period_end_date":"2019-07-31","slope":"0.880000"},"19":{"moving_avg":"114.3333","org_moving_avg":"1.143333","period_end_date":"2019-08-31","slope":"0.870000"},"20":{"moving_avg":"114.6667","org_moving_avg":"1.146667","period_end_date":"2019-09-30","slope":"0.860000"},"21":{"moving_avg":"116.3333","org_moving_avg":"1.163333","period_end_date":"2019-10-31","slope":"0.850000"},"22":{"moving_avg":"118.0000","org_moving_avg":"1.180000","period_end_date":"2019-11-30","slope":"0.830000"},"23":{"moving_avg":"120.0000","org_moving_avg":"1.200000","period_end_date":"2019-12-31","slope":"0.820000"},"24":{"moving_avg":"121.0000","org_moving_avg":"1.210000","period_end_date":"2020-01-31","slope":"0.830000"},"25":{"moving_avg":"120.6667","org_moving_avg":"1.206667","period_end_date":"2020-02-29","slope":"0.840000"},"26":{"moving_avg":"120.3333","org_moving_avg":"1.203333","period_end_date":"2020-03-31","slope":"0.830000"},"27":{"moving_avg":"120.6667","org_moving_avg":"1.206667","period_end_date":"2020-04-30","slope":"0.820000"},"28":{"moving_avg":"122.3333","org_moving_avg":"1.223333","period_end_date":"2020-05-31","slope":"0.810000"},"29":{"moving_avg":"124.0000","org_moving_avg":"1.240000","period_end_date":"2020-06-30","slope":"0.790000"},"30":{"moving_avg":"125.0000","org_moving_avg":"1.250000","period_end_date":"2020-07-31","slope":"0.800000"},"31":{"moving_avg":"127.3333","org_moving_avg":"1.273333","period_end_date":"2020-08-31","slope":"0.760000"},"32":{"moving_avg":"131.3333","org_moving_avg":"1.313333","period_end_date":"2020-09-30","slope":"0.730000"},"33":{"moving_avg":"137.0000","org_moving_avg":"1.370000","period_end_date":"2020-10-31","slope":"0.700000"},"34":{"moving_avg":"142.3333","org_moving_avg":"1.423333","period_end_date":"2020-11-30","slope":"0.680000"},"35":{"moving_avg":"147.0000","org_moving_avg":"1.470000","period_end_date":"2020-12-31","slope":"0.660000"},"36":{"moving_avg":"152.3333","org_moving_avg":"1.523333","period_end_date":"2021-01-31","slope":"0.630000"},"37":{"moving_avg":"159.6667","org_moving_avg":"1.596667","period_end_date":"2021-02-28","slope":"0.590000"},"38":{"moving_avg":"168.0000","org_moving_avg":"1.680000","period_end_date":"2021-03-31","slope":"0.560000"},"39":{"moving_avg":"176.6667","org_moving_avg":"1.766667","period_end_date":"2021-04-30","slope":"0.540000"},"40":{"moving_avg":"182.6667","org_moving_avg":"1.826667","period_end_date":"2021-05-31","slope":"0.540000"},"41":{"moving_avg":"187.3333","org_moving_avg":"1.873333","period_end_date":"2021-06-30","slope":"0.520000"},"42":{"moving_avg":"191.3333","org_moving_avg":"1.913333","period_end_date":"2021-07-31","slope":"0.510000"},"43":{"moving_avg":"195.6667","org_moving_avg":"1.956667","period_end_date":"2021-08-31","slope":"0.500000"},"44":{"moving_avg":"202.0000","org_moving_avg":"2.020000","period_end_date":"2021-09-30","slope":"0.480000"},"45":{"moving_avg":"208.5988","org_moving_avg":"2.085988","period_end_date":"2021-10-31","slope":"0.463400"},"46":{"moving_avg":"216.2373","org_moving_avg":"2.162373","period_end_date":"2021-11-30","slope":"0.448600"},"47":{"moving_avg":"221.7375","org_moving_avg":"2.217375","period_end_date":"2021-12-31","slope":"0.441500"},"48":{"moving_avg":"225.8916","org_moving_avg":"2.258916","period_end_date":"2022-01-31","slope":"0.438100"},"49":{"moving_avg":"228.6755","org_moving_avg":"2.286755","period_end_date":"2022-02-28","slope":"0.432400"},"50":{"moving_avg":"231.0205","org_moving_avg":"2.310205","period_end_date":"2022-03-31","slope":"0.428200"},"51":{"moving_avg":"232.8524","org_moving_avg":"2.328524","period_end_date":"2022-04-30","slope":"0.427800"},"52":{"moving_avg":"235.6036","org_moving_avg":"2.356036","period_end_date":"2022-05-31","slope":"0.417500"}},"base_avg_price":3842,"calculated_value":4500,"selectedMonthData":[{"date":"2021-12-31","price_sqft":"8,519","price":"38,335,500","index":"221.74"},{"date":"2021-06-30","price_sqft":"7,197","price":"32,386,500","index":"187.33"},{"date":"2020-06-30","price_sqft":"4,764","price":"21,438,000","index":"124.00"}]},"index_type":false}'
```

Comment: `cookies={}` and `headers={'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'}` are enough :)

Comment: Thank you @DevConcepts for the solution. It returns the data for the graph but it returns the slope and moving averages of the chart, and not the actual prices which I am looking for.